# css make dynamic <a> link hidden in html

Tags: html, css

Below is the html page. 
There is a dynamic url variable which will generate the  tag. 
As there are other static  tag, the whole css for  tag is applying to all of those links.

How can I control dynamic variable which will generate the  tag using css?
I tried to put that variable insides  tags and not working. Any idea?

```
a { color: #f05322;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover { color: #f05322;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```
<table width="100%" height="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="" bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <tbody>
        <tr height="0" style="padding:0px;vertical-align:top">
            <td height="0" style="padding:0px;">
                <table style="width:900px;  margin:auto;" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="900">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding:20px 10px 10px 35px; " bgcolor="#E6E6E6">
                            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" style="font-size:14px; color:#3A393A;"> © test | <a href="http://www.test.com" target="_blank" style="font-size:14px; color:#3A393A; text-decoration:none;"> www.test.com</a></font>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            ${someURL}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Why you can't use some class for that link? Also, why are you mixing inline and external CSS (worst thing ever)?

Comment: use a class to the dynamic element or its parent to override the default styles..

Comment: using a table to lay out two single items one above the other !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is to add a class to the parent (`td`):

```
<td class="someClass">
    ${someURL}
</td>
```

```css
.someClass a {
    background: yellow;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v7fbc6ea/1/)

When you're unable to change the structure you can target that cell with this CSS:

```
table table tr:nth-of-type(2) a {
    background: yellow;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v7fbc6ea/2/)

Please note that option is the cleanest solution... if you drastically change your structure, you'll need to change option 2 too.